# react js show success and error messages after form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to show success or error message according to my request. currently i am using alert messages for it. How I show this message dynamically. I need to show red color message if error , green color message if success. Can we change div css class and message according to request type.

my fucntion

```
  const saveInvoice = (data) => {
 
const header = {
  Auth_token: `${appUserConfig.accessTokenName}=${appUserConfig.accessToken}`,
  User_name: appUserConfig.userName,
};
console.log(header);
httpPost(SAVE_INVOICE,data, header)
  .then((response) => {
   
    if (response.status === 200) {
     alert("Successfully Save")
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    alert("Error")
    console.log("e:", e);
  });
```

};

I need to do this using single div with changing color and message content.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the style of the alert because alert box is a system object, not a CSS.
You can write your own alert box or use libraries such as [react-alert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert)

Answer (score 0):

The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the alert() functionality.

You can mimic it by creating your own div element with some absolute positioning etc, but i recommend using a portal and creating a modal. or use a library like react toastify etc which can pop the notifications for you.

if you do not want a pop up which can disappear, then use a state like isError, and isSuccess and conditionally render the components